# Preventing duplicate data output from C functions called in Python script

Tags: python, c

I have a python script that execute a compiled C program. Currently, the data exchanged from the C program to the python script is done using printf.

My whole project is starting to grow, with .c functions being called from the .py and the .c itself. This lead me to end some .c functions with both printf and return (like `read()` below).

```c
// This function read a value from a path
char*
read(char* hostname, int port, char* path)
{
    // the data read is attributed to dataValue
    char* dataValue = "test"

    // print the result to be captured from the .py when the function is directly called
    printf("%s", dataValue);

    // return the result for the .c function
    return dataValue;
}

// This function call read() for each path of a list
function1(char* hostname, int port, char** pathArray, int pathArrayCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pathArrayCount; i++) {
        printf("\nReading data of %s\n", hostname);
        result = read(hostname, port, pathArray[i]);
        printf("\ndata = %s", result);
    }
}
```

When `read()` is executed through the .py, the output of printf is captured to be processed in a well formated result.

```py
result = subprocess.run(['./program.c', 'read()', arg1, arg2, arg3], capture_output=True, text=True)
output : result.stdout.strip()
print("output : \n",output)

# *calling read()*
# output :
# test
```

But when `function1()` is executed and call `read()`, the printf in `read()` appear to the terminal and I end up with raw data and well formated data in the terminal.

```
result = subprocess.run(['./program.c', 'function1()', arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4], capture_output=True, text=True)
output : result.stdout.strip()
print("output : \n",output)

# *calling read()*
# output :
# Reading data of localhost
# test
# data = test
```

The output I want when I call the function1 is :

```
output :
Reading data of localhost
data = test
```

How can I prevent this ? My idea was to detect if the .c function is being called from another .c function and skip the printf but I don't know if it's feasible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] instead of just describing your code.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this.
You could add a parameter to the function that determines if it was called from the .py or the .c
Alternatively, you could have a static variable in your c file called "alreadyWrote" and set it to 0. Only write output if the value is 0, and update it to 1 if you do write output.

Both options are a bit cumbersome... You can write a print function that does it for you, and call that instead of the print function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t have functions **both** print values and return them!  Only top-level clients selected by command-line arguments should be printing anything (whether for the user or for consumption by other processes).  You might end up with `read_print` that calls `read` and prints the result as well as `function1_print` that calls `function1` (which calls `read` several times and returns a list of results) and prints the results, but that’s actually only slightly more **total** code than you have here already.

Also consider making your C program into a Python **extension**, so that you can call functions in it directly rather than having to reparse textual output into the same values already available in C.  (If you still want the program for some other purpose, make it and the extension share a library that actually produces the data.)